# How to propagate a parameter through child objects? (Rails 5.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My application manages classifications in which several lists of values are associated to create a hierarchy. A values_to_values table implemtents the links between values, for all classifications:

```
class Value < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :classification_id

  has_many :values_to_values
  has_many :child_values, through: :values_to_values
```

for which the N-N links are stored in:

```
# Table name: values_to_values
#
#  id                    :integer          not null, primary key
#  classification_id     :bigint
#  parent_values_list_id :bigint
#  child_values_list_id  :bigint
#  parent_value_id       :bigint
#  child_value_id        :bigint
```

As a result, a value can be involved in several hierarchies.

When displaying the hierarchy, I query the value_to_values tables as many times as numerous levels the hierarchy contains.
To retrieve only the links relating to the current classification, I need to propagate the classification_id and include it in the query.

I created a get_children method in the values_controller, and added the classification_id attribute to the Value model. To extract child values, I filter the values_to_values with the propagated classification_id attribute:

```
  # GET children from @classification values, including translations for child index
  def get_children
    @values = @value.child_values.where("values_to_values.classification_id = ?", @value.classification_id).includes(:name_translations).order(:code)
    @values.each do |child|
      child.classification_id = @value.classification_id
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index } # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @values }
      format.js # uses specific template to handle js
    end
  end
```

Then I would assign the classification's id to the classification_id virtual attribute to propagate to the next level of the hierarchy. On the first level, classification_id comes through a url parameter, but working with js on DOM for the next levels, I can't use a parameter anymore (or I don't know how to do it).

```
$(function () {
  var itemId = '<%= @values_list.id %>',
      ctId = 'ui-nav-values_list-' + itemId + '-children',
      // create children array (code generated server side)
      children = [
        <% @values.each do |child| %>
          {
            id: '<%= child.id %>',
            code: '<%= child.code %>',
            classification_id: '<%= child.classification_id %>',
            name: '<%= j(translation_for(child.name_translations)) %>',
            url: '<%= url_for(child) %>',
            loadUrl: '<%= url_for(get_children_value_path(child)) %>',
            hasChildren: <%= (!child.child_values.empty?).to_json %>
          },
        <% end %>
      ];

  $('#' + ctId).sisNavigation({
    children: children,
    childLevelId: 'value'
  });
});
```

Unfortunaltely, **the virtual attribute classification_id is not present in the json**, so the query returns no child.

- Is this the right way to achieve this purpose?
- How to retrieve the @values dataset including the virtual attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I found a parial answer:

About `attr_accessor :classification_id`, I finally created a physicall attribute in the values table, which is only used here (poor workaround!).

About propagating the classification_id parameter, I updated the code to definely use it as a parameter:

**get_children.js.erb**

```
$(function () {
  var itemId = '<%= @values_list.id %>',
      ctId = 'ui-nav-values_list-' + itemId + '-children',
      // create children array (code generated server side)
      children = [
        <% @values.each do |child| %>
          {
            id: '<%= child.id %>',
            code: '<%= child.code %>',
            classification_id: '<%= child.classification_id %>',
            name: '<%= j(translation_for(child.name_translations)) %>',
            url: '<%= url_for(child) %>',
            loadUrl: '<%= url_for(get_children_value_path(child, classification_id: child.classification_id)) %>',
            hasChildren: <%= (!child.child_values.empty?).to_json %>
          },
        <% end %>
      ];

  $('#' + ctId).sisNavigation({
    children: children,
    childLevelId: 'value'
  });
});
```

**values_controller**

```
  # GET children from @classification values, including translations for child index
  def get_children
    #@values = @value.child_values.where("values_to_values.classification_id = ?", @classification.id).includes(:name_translations).order(:code)
    @values = @value.child_values.where("values_to_values.classification_id = ?", params[:classification_id]).includes(:name_translations).order(:code)
    @values.each do |child|
      child.classification_id = params[:classification_id]
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index } # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @values }
      format.js # uses specific template to handle js
    end
  end
```

Remarks and alternate solutions are welcome!